# Disable jQuery script when window size is

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disable my jQuery script when window size is less than 700px.
So this script should not be working when window size is under 700px. I could not get it working.
Script does not work when page is loaded, but when I resize browser window then it works no matter what size window is.

Here is my current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        if (jQuery(window).width() < 700) {

            jQuery("#block-menu-block-4 li, #block-menu-block-5 li").hover(

            function () {
                jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
                jQuery(this).children('.listContainer1, .listContainer2, .listContainer3, .listContainer4, .listContainer5, .listContainer6, .listContainer7').stop(true, true).show();
            },

            function () {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');
                jQuery(this).children('.listContainer1, .listContainer2, .listContainer3, .listContainer4, .listContainer5, .listContainer6, .listContainer7').stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
            });

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Warning: You are registering a `hover` event inside a `resize` event so will wind up with 1000s of handlers after few moves of the mouse.

Comment: Off topic, but you'd be far better off only using CSS (including for transitions) rather than trying to do this via JavaScript. You could then target different Viewport sizes for different effects.

Comment: _"I'm trying to disable my jQuery script when window size is less than 700px..."_ - Could be wrong here but it appears your script will attach the first time the window is ***under*** 700 pixels. This seems to be the reverse of what you're asking?...

Comment: if you provide jsfiddle I can get it working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have made one basic (serious) error in registering events inside events. You will currently wind up with 100s/1000s of event handlers connected as you resize, and never remove the old ones, so of course your code keeps executing.

You instead need to registered `hover` once and test for the size inside the `hover` handler.

One alternative is to use 'on`and`off` to turn the handler on and off.

Another is to add a class to the container/body, based on the size, and use a delegated event handler that only matches the specific size/class.